# how to low-level format a hard disk using AIX?

Tags: formatting, format, system-administration, aix

I have a server with AIX 6.1 , I formated some hdisks using diag tool, but in some way some of its VGDA survived.

how may I low-level format a hard disk using AIX?

or

how may I clear the VGDA of a specific hdisk?

thanks

Comment: SuperDuperSuperUser @ http://www.superuser.com/ is your friend ^^

Answer (score 0):

dd if=/dev/zero of= with an optional bs= count= will clear off anything to zero.